# Wagtail Images Not Loading Once Deployed

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail

I'm not quite sure what's going on, but my images loaded fine on my local development server. However, once I deployed, the images will not load. I checked the URL and it seems to be correct. I'm not sure what's going on here.

**base.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**HTML**

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}
...
{% with post.main_image as main_image %}
    {% if main_image %}{% image main_image fill-400x200 %}{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

**Page Source for Element**

```
<img alt="photo" src="/media/images/Lily.2e16d0ba.fill-400x200.jpg" width="400" height="201">
```

I'm pretty confused and I can't really find much about the topic. Am I the only one who's run in to this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During development (when you use `./manage.py runserver` and have the `DEBUG` setting set to True), Django [serves static files itself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) as a convenience. In production, it's up to you to configure your web server to serve static files from `/media` and `/static`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/

This is for performance and security reasons - there's no point having static files served via Python code when there's already a web server properly tuned for that task.